# Find $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $(3+5i,1+3i) = (\alpha)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, principal-ideal-domains

> Let $\mathbb{Z}[i] = \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i) = \{a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$.
>
> Find $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}[i]$ such that $(3+5i,1+3i) = (\alpha)$

**Definition :** If $A$ is a ring et $S \subset A$, then we note $(S)$ the smallest ideal containing S.

I took I lot of time to try solving this problem. Is anyone could help me for this question?

Comment: What did you try and where did you get stuck?

Comment: What kind of $\alpha$ respects this equality? I have only 13 years old; so sometime I have to ask some help.... BTW, I just don't know how to start the problem.

Comment: That's ok. I'm only asking what you've tried as it means we can try and help you at the point where you're stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is a Euclidean domain, every ideal is principal, so $\alpha$ exists and it *is* a greatest common divisor of $3+5i$ and $1+3i$. You could find it with the Euclidean algorithm, but also factorization is possible: a greatest common divisor can be computed from the prime factorization as usual for the integers.

Suppose you know a prime factor $z$; then $3+5i=zw$ for some $w$ and therefore
$$
(3+5i)(3-5i)=34=z\bar{z}w\bar{w}
$$
Since $34=2\cdot 17$ we know that the prime factors of $3+5i$ are among $1+i$, $4+i$ and $4-i$.

Similarly, if $1+3i=zw$ for a prime $z$,
$$
(1+3i)(1-3i)=10=z\bar{z}w\bar{w}
$$
so the prime factors of $1+3i$ are among $1+i$, $2+i$ and $2-i$.

Thus the candidate is $1+i$ and, indeed
$$
\frac{3+5i}{1+i}=\frac{(3+5i)(1-i)}{2}=4+i,
\qquad
\frac{1+3i}{1+i}=\frac{(1+3i)(1-i)}{2}=2+i
$$
so a greatest common divisor is $1-i$.

Note that $4+i$ and $2+i$ are coprime, because $17$ and $5$ are so in $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

How did I find the candidate primes in the decomposition of $3+5i$? The primes in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ are, up to multiplication by units, $1+i$, the couples $a+bi$, $a-bi$ where $a^2+b^2$ is an odd prime integer, and the prime integers $p$ such that $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$.

If $3+5i=zw$, where $z$ is a prime, then $z\bar{z}w\bar{w}$ is a factor of $(3+5i)(3-5i)=34$. But we know from the classification above that $z\bar{z}$ must be $2=(1+i)(1-i)$, an odd prime of the form $a^2+b^2$ or $p^2$ (with $p$ prime and $p\equiv3\pmod{4}$). As the factorization of $3+5i$ is $2\cdot 17$ we know where to look for.

Note that we *do* know that $3+5i$ is divisible by $1+i$, but the method doesn't tell which one among $4+i$ or $4-i$ is a factor; this of course can be checked with a division.

Of course the Euclidean algorithm is faster if the numbers have large modulus, but it's not as easy to perform as in the integers (see [Gaussian integers & division theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655117/gaussian-integers-division-theorem)).

Comment: The problem is $(3+5i, 1+3i)$ is not the gcd. Check in the question, I will edit it.

Comment: @RobertDavis No, it is not the gcd, but $\alpha$ is it nonetheless. The generator of the ideal generated by two elements is their gcd.

Comment: How do you find the factors $1+i$, $4+i$ and $4-i$ for example?

Comment: Note that it was shown that the norm of $3+5i$ is equal to $34=2\cdot17$. Hence $3+5i$ can be written as $(a+bi)(c+di)$ for some elements of norms $2$ and $17$, respectively. It can be for example $a+bi=1+i$ and $c+di=4+i$ etc. In our case by norm of $x+iy$ I mean $x^2+y^2$ (not square root of this).

Answer (score 3):

Hint : $3+5i-2(1+3i)=1-i$. Try use this and fact that $(3+5i,1+3i)$ is an ideal.

Comment: Do I have to find an element $\alpha$ such that $(3+5i)a+(1+3i)b = (\alpha c)$ for $a,b$ and $c \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: it is sort of looking for a gcd, a notion which makes sense in this ring you are considering.

Comment: $(a,b)$ is not the gcd of $a$ and $b$. This is roughly the ideal generated by the set $\{a,b\}$, noted by $(\{a,b\})=(a,b)$

Comment: @RobertDavis In a principal ideal domain, the ideal $(a,b)$ is exactly $(\gcd(a,b))$, the ideal generated by their gcd.  That's why many people use the notation $(a,b)$ for the gcd itself.